Framer motion cursor animation lags for me
I found this cursor animation online and I created a next app and copy pasted that code into my component as it is but the animation is so laggy , then I found it has something to do with next , I created a typescript + SWC react project with vite and copy pasted that code and it still lags
I know these types of questions have been asked previously but this one is a little different in the sense that it works on the codesandbox but not locally , In summary I cant conclude whats the problem causing it to lag so much

High CPU or memory usage from other applications can affect the performance of your web application, including animations.
